# Why is the cookie expiration date set relative to the server's time in IE 10 but relative to the client's time in Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies, express

I have server which has an incorrect system date running node.js/Express acting as a web server.  The server will be at a customer location and may not have access to a time server, so I have to assume the system date will probably be incorrect.  My problem is with cookie expiration.  In my Node program I set the expiration to 15 minutes with the following:

```
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: (1000*60*15]) }, secret: 'secret' }));
```

The cookie expiration date is set to 15 minutes in the future based on the client machine's time in Firefox and Chrome, but based on the server's incorrect time in IE 10.

For example:

If the current local date is Mon, 4 November 2013 10:30:00, with an incorrect server time of Mon, 21 May 2012 06:30:00, my cookie's expiration dates are set to Mon, 4 November 2013 10:45:00 on Firefox and Chrome, but Mon, 21 May 2012 06:45:00 in IE 10. So my Node server thinks the cookies in IE are expired, hence I can't log in.

How can I make IE's cookie expire 15 minutes in the future based on the client machine's time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's changed (which I'm not aware that it has), IE doesn't support `max-age` and you must use `expires` instead ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

If your server time is "off", you may need to send the client's time to the server (which of course would be subject to spoofing), and/or add a second layer of behavior that also checks elapsed time based on server time (regardless of the presence of the cookie), maybe with the value being sent in a cookie.

Comment: Express' cookie implementation seems to be browser independent though because [it only uses _expires_ even when _maxAge_ is set](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/8e57b21bef0d53010c4d37f4beee3f0341f3eaa6/session/cookie.js).